# Using CSS Columns 'page-break-inside' doesn't work with Flexbox 'align-items:center'

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, mozilla

This is only an issue in Mozilla Firefox (tested with latest).

I want a to layout menu items with vertically centered text in four columns.

I would have gone down the `'display: table'` `'vertical-align:middle'` route but that would prevent me from applying truncatation when required and I would prefer not to add an addiotnal wrapper element if possible.

I'm using the following CSS to achieve vertical centering within the menu item which forces a column break in between a menu item:

```
display: flex;

align-items: center;
// or 
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

See Codepen (enabling line 20 or lies 24-25) breaks the layout...

http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/JXzGwE

**Edit**

So, I can achieve the desired layout with a vertical centering 'hack' but I'd prefer to use Flexbox if at all possible.

http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/mPoPPz?editors=1100

I'm ready to put it down to a bug as all other modern browsers display as you'd expect. although I'm curious to know why it's happening and if it's occuring for a specific reason.

Comment: inline-block or inline-flex should avoid to see container break into 2 columns http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pyYyEj

Comment: Yes @GCyrillus. Looks good. Updated your pen with truncation: http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/JXzXbO?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [4. Rules for Breaking](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#breaking-rules):

> Some content is not fragmentable, for example many types of [replaced
>   elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element) (such as images or video), scrollable elements, or a
>   single line of text content. Such content is considered *monolithic*:
>   it contains no possible break points. Any forced breaks within such
>   boxes therefore cannot split the box, and must therefore also be
>   ignored by the box’s own fragmentation context.
>
> In addition to any content which is not generally fragmentable, UAs
>   may consider as [monolithic](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#monolithic) any elements with [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow) set
>   to `auto` or `scroll` and any elements with `overflow: hidden` and a
>   non-`auto` [logical height](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/#block-size) (and no specified maximum logical
>   height).
>
> Since line boxes contain no possible break points, [`inline-block`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)
>   and [`inline-table`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) boxes (and other inline-level [display
>   types](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#display-type) that establish a new [formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#formatting-context)) may also be
>   considered [monolithic](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#monolithic).

So you may use

```css
.menu-item {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 4;
     -moz-columns: 4;
          columns: 4;
}
.menu-item {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 8.333%;
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
     page-break-inside: avoid;
          break-inside: avoid;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 1</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 2</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 3</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 4</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 5</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 6</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 7</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 8</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 9</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 10</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 11</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 12</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 13</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 14</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 15</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 16</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 17</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 18</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 19</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 20</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 21</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 22</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 23</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 24</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 25</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 26</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 27</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 28</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 29</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 30</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 31</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 32</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 33</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 34</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 35</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 36</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 37</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 38</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 39</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 40</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 41</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 42</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 43</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 44</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 45</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 46</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 47</p></a>
</nav>
```

Or, as [GCyrillus commented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37144037/1529630#comment61826828_37144037),

```css
.menu-item {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 4;
     -moz-columns: 4;
          columns: 4;
}
.menu-item {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 8.333%;
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
     page-break-inside: avoid;
          break-inside: avoid;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 1</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 2</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 3</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 4</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 5</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 6</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 7</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 8</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 9</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 10</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 11</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 12</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 13</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 14</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 15</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 16</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 17</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 18</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 19</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 20</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 21</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 22</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 23</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 24</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 25</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 26</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 27</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 28</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 29</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 30</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 31</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 32</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 33</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 34</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 35</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 36</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 37</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 38</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 39</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 40</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 41</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 42</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 43</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 44</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 45</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 46</p></a>
  <a class="menu-item"><p>Menu item 47</p></a>
</nav>
```